# usb devices in angular

Tags: angular, usb, webusb

I can not get access to the usb devices in my angular project, every time I use

```js
await navigator.usb.getDevices();
```

It gives me an empty array, and I have added the listeners:

```js
navigator.usb.addEventListener('connect', ev => {
  console.log('testing on connect');
});
navigator.usb.addEventListener('disconnect', ev => {
  console.log('testing on disconnect');
});
```

But they never get called, if I do a log on the navigator.usb I get an USB object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call navigator.usb.requestDevice() first to allow the user to grant the application access to a USB device. [requestDevice()](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/#dom-usb-requestdevice) takes a [USBDeviceRequestOptions](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/#dictdef-usbdevicerequestoptions), which is used to filter out devices that are not interesting to the application.